# How to generate an array of quarter numbers of a year along with year number based on current date using moment.js in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I want to create an array of quarter numbers along with year number using current timestamp in node js.
For example, current quarter is, Q1 and year is, 2020. Now, I want to create an array like the following.

`quarters = ['Q2-2019','Q3-2019','Q4-2019','Q1-2020']`

In the above array, `Q1` is of year `2020` and remaining 3 are from year `2019`
Basically my requirement is to create array of quarters including present quarter number and past 3 quarter numbers along with year number.

Right now, am getting an array like, `['Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1']` by using the following code given by @Santhosh S. The code is,

```
let quarters = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ].map(i => 
  moment().subtract(i, 'Q').format('[Q]Q')
);

console.log(quarters);
```

Is there anyway to generate this array?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `moment().quarter();` to get current quarter.

Edit: use subtract and format to Quarter. Sample code below

```js
let format      = '[Q]Q';
let quarters = [
  moment().format(format),
  moment().subtract(1, 'Q').format(format),
  moment().subtract(2, 'Q').format(format),
  moment().subtract(3, 'Q').format(format)
];

console.log(quarters);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Or a more concise version:

```js
let quarters = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ].map(i => 
  moment().subtract(i, 'Q').format('[Q]Q')
);

console.log(quarters);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the actual month and add one for the next quarter and the quarter count and get the remainder with four for mapping the quarters.

```js
var month = new Date().getMonth(),
    quarters = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'].map((_, i, a) => a[Math.floor(month / 3 + 1 + i) % 4]);

console.log(quarters);
```

Comment: HI @Nina Scholz your code works fine if Quarter starts in Jan, How about if its in April e.g in India Quarter starts in April. It needs to be based on locale. So doing it using moment would help

Comment: you could change the offset of one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `moment.js`

```
const moment = require('moment');
let out = Array(4).fill().map((_, i) => 'Q' + moment().subtract(9-(3*i), 'months').quarter())
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check MomentJs Quarters: [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/quarter/)

Something like `moment().quarter(Number);` based on the current day and create your Q-array.

Comment: That's not possible as I've already accepted someone's answer. Sorry.

Comment: No problem! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following

```js
function getQuarter(date) {
  // `getMonth` returns an int from 0 to 11.
  return Math.floor(date.getMonth() / 3) + 1;
}

function buildQuartersList(currentQuarter) {
  // `fill` is needed, otherwise, `map` won't run.
  const quartersList = new Array(4).fill().map((element, index) => {
    const quarter = ((index + currentQuarter - 1) % 4) + 1;
    return `Q${quarter}`;
  });
  return quartersList.reverse();
}

function getQuartersList(date) {
  const currentQuarter = getQuarter(date);
  return buildQuartersList(currentQuarter);
}

console.log(getQuartersList(new Date()));
```